# 'Custom user with this Email address already exists' error when trying to update email using forms. Django

Tags: django

please read through my code, my question with screenshots and things i've already tried are after my code.

managers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_feilds):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_feilds)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_feilds):
        extra_feilds.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_feilds.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_feilds.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_feilds.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff = True'))
        if extra_feilds.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_feilds)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser, StripeConnectSetup
from django import forms

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email','first_name', 'last_name')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm, StripeConnectSetupForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def update_user_view(request):
    obj = CustomUser.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    data = {'email': obj.email, 'first_name': obj.first_name, 'last_name': obj.last_name}
    form = CustomUserChangeForm(initial=data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = CustomUser.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
            obj.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            obj.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            obj.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            obj.save()
            return redirect('accounts:update_user')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/update_user.html', context)
```

update_user.html:

```
<h1>Update User Profile</h1>
<hr>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

</form>
```

the problem:
when trying to update my account, if i don't wish to change my email (just my first name or lastname) it displays the error 'Custom user with this Email address already exists'

i have searched for many solutions and the only one that seemed to work is passing through the clean function on the update form as shown below:

forms.py

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email','first_name', 'last_name')
    def clean(self):
        pass
```

this fixes the issue and allows you to update your first or last name without updating your email.

However, this causes another bug.
when i try to change my email to a differnt email that already exists in my database instead of getting the 'Custom user with this Email address already exists' error, it loads this screen instead

[error that is occuring with clean function fix in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czsZR.png)

so the question is how do i stop the 'Custom user with this Email address already exists' error when im not updating my email but allow the error when i am changing my email and that email already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to update the object you should simply pass the keyword argument `instance` to the form instead of passing `initial`. You get the error `'Custom user with this Email address already exists'` because when you write `CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` and it tries to validate the form it considers this as creating a new user and this gives you an error.

From the documentation on [The save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) of `ModelForm`:

> A subclass of **ModelForm** can accept an existing model instance as
> the keyword argument **instance**; if this is supplied, **save()**
> will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, **save()** will
> create a new instance of the specified model

So your view should be like:

```python
def update_user_view(request):
    obj = CustomUser.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    form = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:update_user')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/update_user.html', context)
```

Next change your form back so that the `clean` method is unchanged:

```python
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email','first_name', 'last_name')
```